# Abstract Algebra:Permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

1)Express the permutations $\alpha=(24)\in S_4$ and $\beta=(1)\in S_5$,  as sets.
a) Describe the permutations which are reflexive
b) What types of permutations are partial orders.

Attempt of a solution
I understand that the first permutation is $\{(1,1),(2,4),(3,3),(4,4)\}$
and the second permutation is $\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5)\}$ .
a)Is it sufficient to say A reflexive permutations is (1), (2),(3),(4) for the first part and describe the second part similarly?
b) is it sufficient to say the permutation must be reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive

Comment: Inline math should be delimited by single dollar signs, as $x^2$. Displayed math uses double dollar signs, as $$x^2 =x \cdot x$$

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: I guessed an intended TeXification. Does it look exactly the way it's supposed to be?

Comment: Yes, Jyrki, thanks a lot. Still trying to figure out how to type these things.

Answer (score 2):

It seems these permutations are intended to be expressed as [relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_%28mathematics%29).  E.g. $(123) \in S_4$ would be equivalent to the relation $\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,1),(4,4)\}$.  In this example, this is a way of writing:

- $1$ maps to $2$,
- $2$ maps to $3$,
- $3$ maps to $1$, and
- $4$ maps to $4$ (a fixed point).

Note that the domain and range are both $\{1,2,3,4\}$ since this is a permutation.

Your task is to do this for $(24) \in S_4$ which has the fixed points $1$ and $3$, and for $(1) \in S_5$, which I think is the identity permutation (i.e., all points are fixed).  In the second case, the domain and range will instead be $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

For the second part:

- A [reflexive relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation) contains $(i,i)$ for all $i$ in its domain.  Basically this tells you where everything is mapped to.
- A [partial order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_order#Formal_definition) is reflexive (and antisymmetric and transitive).

Comment: So a partial order permutations is reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive. Ok I thought there would be a special 'type of permutation' eg only identity permutations. thanks for sharing

Comment: That's how I've interpreted the question.  Basically there is only the one reflexive permutation in $S_n$, and the question is whether or not this permutation (interpreted as a relation) has the additional properties (antisymmetric and transitive), but these should be immediate.